# SQL CLR Deployment Issue

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Hi I am new to this SQL CLR. I have created a SQL CLR project and complies without any errors. When I try to deploy the code I am getting this below error,

.....\bin\Debug\xxx.sql(85-85): Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 701, Level 17, State 11, Line 1 There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4276.0 (X64) version.

Also when I run the SQL profiler when I deploy this code this deployment stops after this long line of code

> CREATE ASSEMBLY [solaceVHI]
>       AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
>       FROM 0x4D5A9000030000000400.... 037D0E0100042A1E027B0F0100042A2.... E4A007A0303C2000000008608550E3C...
>   53716C436F6E746578740053716C5069....
>       WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;

I have enough memory on my SQL server.

The event virewer error log says ... "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query".

Comment: Do you have all cumulative updates applied for your version of SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks Love2Learn. Yes I did search in Google but I never thought it was something to do with the hotfixs.

Comment: Still might not be, but that baseline stuff is always a good place to start. There is a bug in a version of SQL Server 2012 where you can deadlock on a temp table (non-global) from two separate SPIDs. When something just doesn't make sense, assume it's Microsoft's fault until proven otherwise. ;)

Comment: Thanks Love2Learn you are awesome .... I installed the two hotfixes for SQL Server 2008 R2 . but still I am getting the same error :(

Comment: "with permission_set unsafe" sounds like something.  1) Is the code signed with a "stong name"? 2) is your assembly in the gac?  3) solaceVHI, is that your assembly or possibly a dependent assembly?  Are there any related assemblies that also need to be loaded (gac)?

Comment: Hi tgolisch I am trying to deploy this from VS2010 to SQL 2008 R2. solaceVHI is the name of SQL CLR project.